# Read CP932 type file into String in Java 6

Tags: java, character-encoding

I want to read file content into java String objects whose character encoding is "CP932".

I am using Java 6.

When i try to read it will throw exception:

```
  "UnsupportedChasetEncoding"
```

I have tried following things for the same but I was failed:

```
  1. FileUtils (Apache common IO)
  2. Gauva
  3. Scanner class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charsets supported by Java and their proper names are listed here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

It looks like spelling the name as "MS932" or "windows-31j" should work.